# Does an HttpHandler require an aspnet_isapi.dll mapping

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler, web-config

If I configure (via web.config) an httphandler to handle all .gif requests for a specific folder, is it absolutely essential for me to map .gif requests to aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS?

Is there any other way of ensuring that the .gif http request will be handled by aspnet_isapi.dll?

I have a server configured where the virtual dir that contained the .gif->aspnet_isapi.dll mapping has been deleted, but the .gif requests are still being passed to the handler.  Anyone know how this might be being done, and where the setting might be lurking?

Thanks

Comment: What version of IIS?  6?

Comment: As for the second part of the question.  Have you restarted the App Pool or IIS itself?  Removing that IIS mapping should stop the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is required otherwise IIS will never send the request to ASP.Net and your handler will never have a chance to process the request.

There is no other way that I know of.  You have to let IIS know at some point that it has to handle the file type.

To remove, you can follow the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx but delete rather than add the extension mapping.

Also check that you do not have a wildcard mapping in there as well.

Comment: My concern is that the Vir Dir that contained the mapping has been removed, but the mapping still seems to be working.  That is fine for now, I just don't like not understanding how the current setup is actually working